# Postgres 9.2 to 9.5 Upgrade is losing Data

Tags: postgresql, centos7, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.5

We are attempting to upgrade a production 9.2 postgres cluster to 9.5. The server is running Centos 7 with the Centos version - currently 9.2.15  We are installing the postgresql provided rpm of postgresql9.5 from the postgresql repo, currently 9.5.4.  In testing and on our development cluster, the upgrade worked without issue but something is happening on our production DB that we can not figure out.

The 9.2 cluster is in streaming replication controlled by pacemaker.  Steps we have been using are the following.

1. verify the replica server is in a good state with up to date data, then put the machine in standby, stopping the 9.2 db
2. Starting the 9.2 server manually to get some stats to verify later (counts of rows from several key tables)
3. Stop the 9.2 server, install the 9.5 binaries.
4. init the 9.5 db
5. run a pg_upgrade with the link option
6. run the full vacuum analyze script that pg_upgrade generated

What we are finding in testing is we get thru the upgrade process, start the 9.5 server manually to compare the row counts we collected immediately before the upgrade and we are seeing different data, sometimes drastically.   This data includes missing user accounts, etc, that is not perishable data.

We have enabled verbose logging and have reviewed it but are seeing no errors in the migration.  The 9.5 server starts without complaint and if we did not do these manual checks we would not see a problem.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

The only 'hack' during the upgrade that isn't straight from the postgres_upgrade man page is to handle a renamed option in postgresql that centos backported.  Using the rename of pg_ctl that is referenced in the top answer here - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50135/pg-upgrade-unrecognized-configuration-parameter-unix-socket-directory

Answer (score 0):

Thinking through this (no, I haven't run into the same problem), pg_upgrade works by rewriting the system catalogs but leaving the rest of the data on the disk as is.  If row counts are changing that is quite worrisome.  Nevertheless 9.2 to 9.5 is a pretty big step so there are areas where additional problems can come into play.

Not having the foggiest idea what the actual problem is, the first thing I would try would be to try running vacuum analyze before the upgrade  rather than after.  I am wondering if there is a problem in transaction visibility.

the second thing I would try would be to go to 9.4 instead and see if the problem surfaces and if not, then go to 9.5.

However, I have never even heard of problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL)